html canvas draw straight line
I want to use MS paint style line tool to draw straight line using UI on html canvas element using JS.
The issue is that line preview must be visible on canvas as mouse is being dragged after click at starting position (line preview is basically straight line from starting click point to current mouse position). Once mouse shifts to new position without release, the old line preview should vanish and new one should show. Finally, once mouse is released, the final line should be painted on the canvas. Instead, I get the kind of image you see below.
I tried various ways to perform the following steps in this order but no success:
Loop steps 2. and 3. until mouse released:

Store current image on canvas.
Paint straight line from starting point to current cursor position.
Restore previous image seen in step #1 on canvas upon detecting mouse movement.
Paint final straight line from starting point to current cursor position on mouse release.

window.onload = function() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('paintCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });
    
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    let painting = false;
    let startX, startY;
    let canvasState = false;

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', endPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);

    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    function startPosition(e) {
        painting = true;
        [startX, startY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        draw(e);
    }

    function endPosition() {
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
        painting = false;
        canvasState = false;
    }

    function draw(e) {
        if (!painting) return;

        if (selectedTool.id === 'pencil') {
            ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
            ctx.stroke();
        } else if (selectedTool.id === 'line') {
            // write code that works with a line 
            if (e.type === 'mousemove') {
                // remove old preview line
                if (canvasState) {
                    ctx.putImageData(canvasState, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    canvasState = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                }
                // paint straight line from original start to current mouse position
                ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
                ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        } else if (selectedTool.id === 'eraser') {
            if (e.type === 'mousedown') {
                ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
                ctx.lineWidth += 5;      
            } else {
                ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
                ctx.stroke();    
            }
        }
    }

};




I think, this is because of canvasState is restored inside the path building. The following fix solved the problem for me:
        // remove old preview line
        if (canvasState) {
            ctx.putImageData(canvasState, 0, 0);
        } else {
            canvasState = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        }
        // paint straight line from original start to current mouse position
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
        ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();


thanks for identifying the root cause. It fixed the issue.

to throttle the line repaint, i added ---> let [endX, endY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY]; after ctx.stoke() and then return early from draw function if distance between (endX,endY) and e.offsetX, e.offsetY is less than lineWidth.

Why not make the preview line updates dynamically as the mouse moves and the final line drawn accurately when the mouse is released.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas Line Tool</title>
    <style>
        #paintCanvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="paintCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            const canvas = document.getElementById('paintCanvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
            canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

            ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            let painting = false;
            let startX, startY;
            let canvasState = null;

            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', endPosition);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);

            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.lineCap = 'round';

            function startPosition(e) {
                painting = true;
                [startX, startY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
                canvasState = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
            }

            function endPosition() {
                painting = false;
                ctx.putImageData(canvasState, 0, 0); 
                drawFinalLine(); // Draw the final line
            }

            function draw(e) {
                if (!painting) return;
                ctx.putImageData(canvasState, 0, 0); 
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
                ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            function drawFinalLine() {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
                ctx.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>


this is exactly what my code was aimed at but beginPath() call was not placed correctly.


...Once mouse shifts to new position without release, the old line
preview should vanish and new one should show...

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but judging from the image, your problem is that the new line does not remove the previous one and hence, just like in the image, you have all the lines on the canvas.
Look at this approach:


const canvas = document.getElementById('sketch');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let isDrawing = false;
let startX, startY;

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            startX = e.offsetX;
            startY = e.offsetY;
            isDrawing = true;
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            if (isDrawing) {
                const currentX = e.offsetX;
                const currentY = e.offsetY;

                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
                ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
            if (isDrawing) {
                const endX = e.offsetX;
                const endY = e.offsetY;

                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
                ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
                ctx.stroke();

                isDrawing = false;
            }
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            if (isDrawing) {
                isDrawing = false;
            }
        });
#sketch {
border: 2px solid red;
display: block;
margin: 20px auto;
}
<canvas id="sketch" width="800" height="600"></canvas>



EDIT
If you want keep lines on canvas:


 const canvas = document.getElementById('sketch');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let isDrawing = false;
let startX, startY;
let lines = [];

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    startX = e.offsetX;
    startY = e.offsetY;
    isDrawing = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    if (isDrawing) {
        const currentX = e.offsetX;
        const currentY = e.offsetY;

        redrawCanvas();

        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
        ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    if (isDrawing) {
        const endX = e.offsetX;
        const endY = e.offsetY;

        lines.push({startX, startY, endX, endY});

        isDrawing = false;
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    if (isDrawing) {
        isDrawing = false;
    }
});

function redrawCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    lines.forEach(line => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(line.startX, line.startY);
        ctx.lineTo(line.endX, line.endY);
        ctx.stroke();
    });
}
 #sketch {
border: 2px solid red;
display: block;
margin: 20px auto;
}
<canvas id="sketch" width="800" height="600">




I did not try this solution but it appears you are clearing the whole canvas before repainting - this is not desirable as it doesn't preserve the other strokes on the canvas.

@jam I thought that's what you meant in the quote from your question that I quoted in my answer. Look at edit, if I good understand your needs.
